# Airflow throws warning "Import from airflow.hooks.[operator_module] instead"

Tags: airflow

I am relatively new to airflow and I keep hitting warnings that say

```
DeprecationWarning: Importing 'MsSqlHook' directly from 'airflow.hooks' has been deprecated. Please import from 'airflow.hooks.[operator_module]' instead. Support for direct imports will be dropped entirely in Airflow 2.0.
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here and what will be changed? I typically write my database login into PythonOperator functions using hooks to connect to the DB. Is this no longer allowed in 2.0? I am missing some contextual information it seems.

Comment: We are also missing some contextual information. Show us your related code!

Answer (score 2):

What version of Airflow are you using?
(answer might change based on that)

---

Here's what i think

- You are importing the hook from [`__ini__.py` of `hooks` package](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/hooks/__init__.py), which is [deprecated](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/hooks/__init__.py#L90).
- Instead change your import statement to `from airflow.hooks.mssql_hook import MsSqlHook`, so that you are importing it from [`mssql_hook.py` module](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/hooks/mssql_hook.py) instead

---

Do note that

- even this updated import statement [will itself get deprecated](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/mssql_hook.py#L26) in future releases (v2.0) of Airflow.
- then you might have to (again) update your import statement to `from airflow.providers.microsoft.mssql.hooks.mssql import MsSqlHook`